# Request method 'POST' not supported 405 ERROR

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

This question could be duplicated buy i have tried a lot of solutions.
here is my controller, i have tried on a "restcontroller" to.
I read in a post : i could be a problem with roles (security) but i removed all tag and it is free and i log in as a admin.
Edit:
I forgot to mention, i have a main path "/giro" then in my JS i point to "giro/saveExpress"

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveExpress", method = {RequestMethod.POST}, produces = { "application/json" })
public String saveExpress(@RequestBody String nombreGiro) {
    Giro giro = new Giro();
    giro.setDetalles(nombreGiro);
    giroService.save(giro);     
    return "exito";
    
}
```

html (inside a modal):

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group row">
    <form id="btnGiro" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <textarea name="nombreGiro" id="nombreGiro" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
    </form>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

My javascript:
$(document).ready(
function() {

```
        // SUBMIT FORM
        $("#btnGiro").submit(function(event) {
            alert('hi');
            // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
            event.preventDefault();
            ajaxPost();
        });

        function ajaxPost() {
            var data = {}
            data["nombreGiro"] = $("#nombreGiro").val();
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: 'application/json',
                 url: "/giro/saveExpress",
                 data: JSON.stringify(data),
                 dataType: 'json',
                 timeout: 600000,
                 success: function (data) {
                     $("#btnGiro").prop("disabled", false);
                     //...
                 },
                 error: function (e) {
                     $("#btnGiro").prop("disabled", false);
                     //...
                 }
        });

        }

    })
```

Comment: End point is "/saveExpress" or "/giro/saveExpress" ?

Comment: Could you add the whole repsonse with headers and body to your question? There must be an `allow` header, which shows the allowed HTTP methods.

Comment: I edited. I have a main path in my controller. "/giro" then. is "/giro/saveExpress".

Comment: Can you show me how @NakulGoyal ? I thought i was not necesary, i am in the same domain.